# Selenium with Django. Error import webdriver

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am using Selenium, inside a Django Project. I am using it in views.py, inside to my app, and I link it by url.

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def allyears(br):
   global browser
   path = os.environ['PATH']
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/"+path+"/chromedriver)
   browser.get('https://www.address.com/recipes/))
```

I am trying to install `Webdriver Chrome` in a `Django` project. I linked to path environment, but not working. Anyway, when I will update it to a server, I can not link to a physical route.

So, how can import `webdriver.Chrome` or `webdriver.Firefox` in Django?

Comment: https://www.dev2qa.com/python-automation-scripts-examples-use-django-and-selenium/

Comment: Thanks. My question was, Is there some way for import webdriver without use a route in my disk? I will need to update in a server.